# Detecting real path from which a ClickOnce application has been installed

Tags: .net, vb.net, clickonce

I want to execute a ClickOnce application by its name, from within another C# application.
My current method gets the path to the .Application file from the Uninstall registry key (HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[PublicKeyToken]\ShortcutAppId.

We have a network folder where all our ClickOnce applications are stored.  Every shortcut to a ClickOnce application targets the .Application file in that folder.

I have a problem when the application was deployed to Z:\ClickOnceApps\MyApp but was installed from \\server\share\ClickOnceApps\MyApp\MyApp.application.  In that case, the ShortcutAppId stored in the registry is Z:\ClickOnceApps\MyApps\MyApps.Application#[...]  When I try to launch the application using this path, it offers me to install it, which makes me think that the actual install path is part of the application identity.

So basically I can only launch an application from the same path it was installed.

My question : How can I retrieve the precise path from which the application was installed (and not the deployment path) ?

Here's my code to retrieve the ShortcutAppId for those interested :

```
Public Class ClickOnceApp

        Public Property DisplayName As String
        Public Property UninstallString As String
        Public Property PublicKeyToken As String
        Public Property DisplayVersion As Version
        Public Property ShortcutAppId As String

        Public ReadOnly Property ShortcutPath As String
            Get

                Dim pawnIndex = ShortcutAppId.IndexOf("#"c)
                If pawnIndex = -1 Then
                    Return ""
                Else
                    Return ShortcutAppId.Substring(0, pawnIndex)
                End If

            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub New(appUninstallKey As RegistryKey)

            Me.DisplayName = appUninstallKey.GetValue("DisplayName")
            Me.UninstallString = appUninstallKey.GetValue("UninstallString")
            Me.PublicKeyToken = appUninstallKey.GetValue("PublicKeyToken")
            Me.DisplayVersion = New Version(appUninstallKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"))
            Me.ShortcutAppId = appUninstallKey.GetValue("ShortcutAppId")

        End Sub

        Public Sub Launch()
            Process.Start(ShortcutPath)
        End Sub

    End Class


    Public Class ClickOnceHelper

        Public Shared Function GetInstalledClickOnceApps() As ClickOnceApp()

            Dim list As New List(Of ClickOnceApp)()

            Using uninstallKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")

                For Each subKeyName In (From keyName In uninstallKey.GetSubKeyNames() _
                                    Where keyName.Length = 16)

                    Using appKey = uninstallKey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName)

                        If CStr(appKey.GetValue("UninstallString")).StartsWith("rundll32.exe dfshim.dll") Then

                            Dim app = New ClickOnceApp(appKey)
                            list.Add(app)

                        End If

                    End Using

                Next

            End Using

            Return list.ToArray()

        End Function

        Public Shared Function FindClickOnceAppByName(name As String) As ClickOnceApp

            Dim list = GetInstalledClickOnceApps()
            Return (From app In list _
                    Where app.DisplayName.ToLower() = name.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault()

        End Function

        Public Shared Function FindClickOnceAppByPublicKey(publicKeyToken As String) As ClickOnceApp

            Dim list = GetInstalledClickOnceApps()
            Return (From app In list _
                    Where app.PublicKeyToken = publicKeyToken).FirstOrDefault()
        End Function

End Class
```